# Android ListView and ArrayAdapter implementation

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

So, I'm trying to create a screen that when clicking a button this takes the data from some EditText and add them to a ListView item, now I know there are a lot of examples on the web and I've done them and they work, but when I took them to what I want to do it just adds one item and stops working it doesn't throw any exception or anything, it just add one item, this is what I got so far...

create_class.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.eduardolaguna.mariela.app.activities.CreateClass">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/cc_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/cc_hint_class_name" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/cc_divider1"
                style="@style/Divider"
                android:layout_below="@+id/cc_name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_cc_professors_data"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/cc_divider1"
                android:text="@string/cc_tv_professors_data" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/cc_professors_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tv_cc_professors_data"
                android:hint="@string/cc__hint_professors_name"
                android:inputType="textPersonName|textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/cc_professors_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/cc_professors_name"
                android:hint="@string/cc_hint_professors_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/cc_professors_phonenumber"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/cc_professors_email"
                android:hint="@string/cc_hint_professors_phonenumber"
                android:inputType="phone" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/cc_divider2"
                style="@style/Divider"
                android:layout_below="@id/cc_professors_phonenumber" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_cc_schedule"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/cc_divider2"
                android:text="@string/cc_tv_class_schedule" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/sp_cc_day_of_the_week"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tv_cc_schedule"
                android:entries="@array/dow" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/cc_from_schedule"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/sp_cc_day_of_the_week"
                android:hint="@string/cc_hint_from_schedule"
                android:inputType="time" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/cc_to_schedule"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/sp_cc_day_of_the_week"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cc_from_schedule"
                android:hint="@string/cc_hint_to_schedule"
                android:inputType="time" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/cc_floor_number"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/sp_cc_day_of_the_week"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cc_to_schedule"
                android:hint="@string/cc_hint_floor"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/cc_classroom"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/sp_cc_day_of_the_week"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cc_floor_number"
                android:hint="@string/cc_hint_classroom" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_cc_add_schedule"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/cc_from_schedule"
                android:text="@string/cc_add_schedule" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/cc_schedule_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/btn_cc_add_schedule" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

schedule_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sch_day_of_the_week"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Miércoles"
        android:textSize="60dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sch_from"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5:45"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sch_to"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="7:15"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sch_floor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="7"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sch_clasroom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="lab1"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

ScheduleAdapter.java

```
public class ScheduleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Actividad> {

    private int layoutResourceId;

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private List<Actividad> shifts;


    public ScheduleAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Actividad> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        layoutResourceId = resource;
        shifts = objects;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        Holder holder = null;

        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, null);

        holder = new Holder();
        holder.actividad = shifts.get(position);
        holder.dow = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.sch_day_of_the_week);
        holder.fromTXT = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.sch_from);
        holder.toTXT = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.sch_to);
        holder.floorTXT = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.sch_floor);
        holder.roomTXT = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.sch_clasroom);

        setupItem(holder);
        row.setTag(holder);
        return row;
    }

    private void setupItem(Holder holder) {
        holder.dow.setText(holder.actividad.getDiaDeLaSemana());
        holder.fromTXT.setText(holder.actividad.getDesdeStr());
        holder.toTXT.setText(holder.actividad.getHastaStr());
        holder.floorTXT.setText(holder.actividad.getPiso());
        holder.roomTXT.setText(holder.actividad.getSalon());
    }

    public static class Holder {
        Actividad actividad;
        TextView dow;
        TextView fromTXT;
        TextView toTXT;
        TextView floorTXT;
        TextView roomTXT;
    }
}
```

And finally the CreateClass.java
public class CreateClass extends ActionBarActivity {

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create_class);

        ListView view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.cc_schedule_list);
        final ScheduleAdapter adapter = new ScheduleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.schedule_item, new ArrayList<Actividad>());
        view.setAdapter(adapter);

        Button addSchedule = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cc_add_schedule);
        addSchedule.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Resources res = getResources();

                ListView scheduleView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.cc_schedule_list);
                ScheduleAdapter adapter1 = (ScheduleAdapter) scheduleView.getAdapter();

                Actividad act = new Actividad(TipoEvento.CLASE);
                Spinner dow = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_cc_day_of_the_week);
                act.setDiaDeLaSemana(dow.getSelectedItem().toString());

                TextView from = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cc_from_schedule);
                act.setDesdeStr(res.getString(R.string.from) + ": " + from.getText().toString());

                TextView to = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cc_to_schedule);
                act.setHastaStr(res.getString(R.string.to) + ": " + to.getText().toString());

                TextView floor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cc_floor_number);
                act.setPiso(res.getString(R.string.floor) + ": " + floor.getText().toString());

                TextView classroom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cc_classroom);
                act.setSalon(res.getString(R.string.classroom) + ": " + classroom.getText().toString());

                adapter1.add(act);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: If you put a toast inside onClick(), does it appear each time you press the button?

Comment: Yes, I've debuged the app and the onClick event is allways fire

Comment: You might want to try `adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged()` or in the adapter setup `adapter1.setNotifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem is the ListView is inside the ScrollView, this does not work properly when the list grows dynamically, I move it out the ScrollView and it works like a charm.

This was [according to @Romain Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3496042/381288) a developer in the Android project, where he stated that

> Using a ListView to make it not scroll is extremely expensive and goes against the whole purpose of ListView. You should NOT do this. Just use a LinearLayout instead.

So I use a LinearLayout to draw the new items on the layout.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should instantiate your adapter with the `Activity` context, not the application context.
2. Storing a copy of the constructed list in `shifts` can be [dangerous](http://jaysoyer.wordpress.com/2014/07/13/problems-with-the-arrayadapter-the-constructors/).
3. Don't store `shifts` in the Holder. Only views go in there.
4. When populating the convertView, reference the internal `getItem(position)` method to obtain the `Actividad` data...not your `shifts` variable.
5. You're also using the ViewHolder paradigm incorrectly. [Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13165506/1243753).

Comment: Thanks @Jay I'll take notice of your recommendations